# How do I get the ID of the currently authenticated Twitter user in a web application without using OAuth?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

*Apologies in advance for the long background but I think it is necessary and helpful to other devs once this is answered.

## Background

I am building a very social web-application in which there are several events that trigger social actions such as updating the user's Twitter status.

Currently, I use a library called "TweetMoaSharp" (.NET) to handle the Oauth workflows and events that trigger a status update or follow action work brilliantly **as long as the user is briefly redirected to the Twitter authentication page.**

To clarify, the user is not asked to re-authorize my app each time, but there is an unsightly flicker that lasts for 1-2 seconds while the user is directed to Twitter and then back to my app. This will annoy the end user as there are frequent Twitter interactions.

So--to relieve the situation, I use TweetMoaSharp to obtain an OAuth Access Token via the server and then store that token along with the user id returned from Twitter in my database.  I then set a cookie on the client that contains the user's Twitter Id so that for future requests I can simply pass that ID to the server, grab the OAuth token form the database and do my business.  No redirect required!

## Problem Solved, Right?

Well, no.  Stupidly, I overlooked the fact that this can cause a collision with multiple Twitter Accounts being used on the same page and ended up tweeting test-tweets to a second twitter account I own because I had changed Twitter sessions.  This could happen to any user(s) who access multiple Twitter accounts from the same browser; a husband and wife for example.

## Back to the Drawing Board

I thought to myself, "The Facebook JavaScript API" makes it super easy to get the id of the currently logged in user without going through a bunch of server-side token steps so I am sure Twitter offers the same approach."  Ha!  I haven't found one yet.

## Bottom Line / Question

How do I get the ID of the currently authenticated Twitter user without redirecting them to Twitter (even for just a second)?  If I can do this, then I can compare the returned ID to the one in my cookie and know if it is valid for my application's current session or if I need to have that (new) user authenticate as well so that I avoid "Tweeting" under the wrong account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might find more help on the twitter developer forum

https://twittercommunity.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use your app tokens to do a [verify credentials call](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials)

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json

The returned info is the logged in user.

Unfortunately limited to 15 calls per 15 minute window!